# back button not working in Shell navigation Xamarin MAUI in multiple layer navigation

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui, .net-maui.shell

When I try to navigate into multiple-layer navigation, the back button not working.

Let's say first goes into the "dashboard" page then I go into the "animals" page then if I try the back button it's working fine, but if I go deeper into the "cats" page and then try the back button it not working. I check both windows and android devices.

1.`<ShellContent Title="Home" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:DashBoard}" Route="DashBoard" />`

2.`await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("animals");`

3.`await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("cats");`

am I missing something here, please help me out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, I figure out what was the problem, it was this -

```
<ShellContent Title="Home" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:DashBoard}" Route="DashBoard" />
```

but it needs to be like this -

```
<ShellContent Title="Home" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:DashBoard}" />
```

so the main problem is that I declared
`Route="DashBoard"` in Xaml also I'm Registering in cs like this -  `Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(DashBoard), typeof(DashBoard))` which creates ambiguity.

Comment: This answer is excellent, I think the MUAI should throw a conflict exception in this situation.

Comment: this answer is pretty good

Comment: Brilliant answer!